# Datetime ISO 8601

Tags: php, date, datetime

Working in a project find a problem. If see ISO 8601, the following is a valid date-time representation: 1997-09-02T10 (representing 09 September 1997, 10:00). BUT:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam");

$dateObject = new DateTime( '2012-02-02T10', $tz );

echo $dateObject->format( 'j F Y H:i' );
```

Give me an error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ('2012-02-02T10').

What is this??

Comment: What's the whole error message?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ('2012-02-02T10')

Comment: I get the more descriptive _Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2012-02-02T10) at position 11 (1): Unexpected character' in php shell code:1_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You input format is not valid. See [supported input date and time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Try this instead:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam");
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d\TH',  '2012-02-02T10', $tz);
echo $dateObject->format('j F Y H:i');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/67087).

Comment: No,see- http://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/iso8601.php. Of course I can use as you write, but why if following this standard, the error is appear???

Comment: @sergio PHP doesn't support all valid ISO 8601 inputs, so it doesn't matter if it's a valid ISO 8601 format, it only matters if it's supported by PHP.

Comment: @sergio: If you add minute part, you can use it as your question example, [see demo](https://eval.in/67089). Like cbuckley said, PHP doesn't support all iso-8601 formats. See link in my answer, what kind of formats does php support.